# Check angle between two lines greater than 90 ?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I want to determine whether the measure of angle Q is greater than 90 degrees.

Comment: it's less than 90 degrees ;-)

Comment: Suggestion - use the cosine rule

Comment: If the lines are *not* perpendicular, then there **always** be an angle greater than $\;90^\circ\;$ and one less than that between them...One way to avoid this double result is to look at the inner prodcut definition of the cosine when we *decide* what vectors to take.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calculate as follows (in C# or any similar language):

```
 ux = x2 - x1  ;  uy = y2 - y1;   // u = (ux,uy) = vector from p1 to p2
 vx = x3 - x1  ;  vy = y3 - y1;   // v = (vx,vy) = vector from p1 to p3
 d = ux*vx + uy*vy;               // Dot product of u and v
```

So, the number $d$ is the dot product of the vectors $ \mathbf{u} =\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{p}_3 - \mathbf{p}_1$. If $ d<0$, then the angle between the vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is greater than 90 degrees. If you actually want to find the angle, it's a bit more work (but that's not what you asked).

Answer (score 1):

Form the vectors (x3 - x1, y3 - y1) and (x2 - x1, y2 - y1) and take the dot product. The dot product, from there you can get cosine of the angle between the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not trying:
$$
\cos(Q),
$$
if it is greater than $0$ the angle is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, otherwise it is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.

Comment: What about tan(Q) ?

Comment: You can use it as well, but if the angle is exactly $\pi/2$ you have a not defined $\tan(\pi/2)$. If you're sure a priori that the angle will not be $\pi/2$ it is equivalent to use bot cosine and tangent functions.